# Simplify a long IF statement in PHP

Tags: php, validation, session, conditional-statements, is-empty

Is there any simpler format for the following `if` statement below?

```
if((!empty($_SESSION['email'])) && (!empty($_SESSION['serial'])) && (!empty($_SESSION['name'])) && (!empty($_SESSION['number'])) && (!empty($_SESSION['institution'])) && (!empty($_SESSION['address'])) && (!empty($_SESSION['item2']))){ 
    echo "OK u can proceed";
} else {
    echo "U didn't complete the requested info";
}
```

Sorry if this is too simple for you, but really appreciate any pro suggestion.

Comment: Why don't you just have a `!empty($_SESSION); `

Comment: This isn't equivalent, @Akintunde. What if there's some more information in `$_SESSION`? It won't be empty, but maybe the required values are.

Comment: I tried !empty($_SESSION), it didn't work like what I expect. I think it means : as long as it is not empty, even 1 out of 10 parameters exist. But what I want is 10 out out 10 parameters must be fulfilled.

Comment: I should ask if you are aware of `empty()`'s assumptions about zero-ish, empty-ish values.  Is there any chance that valid values will be passed via these elements that will cause an unintended failure by `empty()`?  Please read the manual if you are unsure what I mean: http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because conditional statement will "short circuit" on the first failure, re-writing your process using an iterator will be less performant.

If you only want to provide generalized feedback to the user, use your current method without the surplus parentheticals.

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['email']) &&
   !empty($_SESSION['serial']) &&
   !empty($_SESSION['name']) &&
   !empty($_SESSION['number']) &&
   !empty($_SESSION['institution']) &&
   !empty($_SESSION['address']) &&
   !empty($_SESSION['item2'])){
    // valid
}
```

Alternatively (same same):

```
if(empty($_SESSION['email']) ||
   empty($_SESSION['serial']) ||
   empty($_SESSION['name']) ||
   empty($_SESSION['number']) |
   empty($_SESSION['institution']) ||
   empty($_SESSION['address']) ||
   empty($_SESSION['item2'])){
    // invalid
}
```

Only if you wish to specify the cause of the invalidation should you bother to set up an iterative process.  Furthermore, if you are going to perform iterations to validate, you can take the opportunity to remove any unwanted elements from the `$_SESSION` array that evil-doers may have injected to take advantage of any future loops on the superglobal.

```
$valid_keys=['email','serial','name','number','institution','address','item2'];
$validated=true; // default value
foreach($valid_keys as $key){
    if(!empty($_SESSION[$key])){
        $session_data[$key]=$_SESSION[$key];
    }else{
        echo "Oops, there was missing data on $key";
        $validated=false;
        break;
    }
}
if($validated){...
// from this point, you can confidently run loops on `$session_data` or slap it directly into a pdo call knowing that it has been validated and ordered.
```

---

All that said, if there is even the slightest chance that your `$_SESSION` elements could hold zero-ish/false-y/empty values, then [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) is the better call (only `NULL` will get caught).  Another good thing about `isset()` is that it allows multiple variables to be written into the single call and maintains the same/intended performance.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['email'],$_SESSION['serial'],$_SESSION['name'],$_SESSION['number'],$_SESSION['institution'],$_SESSION['address'],$_SESSION['item2'])){
    // valid
}
```

or

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['email'],$_SESSION['serial'],$_SESSION['name'],$_SESSION['number'],$_SESSION['institution'],$_SESSION['address'],$_SESSION['item2'])){
    // invalid
}
```

Comment: Is the 3rd method the one that can tell user which part is not completed?

Comment: Yes, that is the option to use if you want to be highly informative about the cause of the invalidation.  There are cases when you want to be informative and cases when you want to keep this info secret for security purposes.

Answer (score 1):

You could build a function where you pass all the keys you want to check.
I've changed `$_SESSION` to `$SESSION` to cheat the array with some values ...

```
<?php

$SESSION = [
    'email' => 'xx',
    'serial' => 'xx',
    'name' => 'xx',
    'number' => 'xx',
    'institution' => 'xx',
    'address' => 'xx',
    'item2' => 'xx'
];

$keys = [
    'email',
    'serial',
    'name',
    'number',
    'institution',
    'address',
    'item2'
];

if(isNotEmpty($SESSION, $keys)) {
    echo "OK u can proceed";
} else {
    echo "U didn't complete the requested info";
}

function isNotEmpty($array, $keys) {
    foreach($keys as $key) {
        if(empty($array[$key])) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

[PHP Fiddle](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/618e217980186cb73c5e4d88c91412408756eca1)

Comment: No early `break;` in the loop?

Comment: @mickmackusa what do you think, better?

Comment: That's clean.  ...wait a second, do you need to pass SUPERGLOBALS to the function or is it already available.

Comment: I think if using the real `$_SESSION` we do not need to pass it as it will be available in the function. But to get the PHP Fiddle to work I had to pass it in....

Comment: Yep, that `isEmpty` function is much more clean than mine. Thanks @caramba

Comment: Thanks @JordiNebot appreciate!

Comment: Also, passing `$_SESSION` to the function allows the function to be reused to check other arrays.

Comment: That's a fair point, better to name the parameter `$array` so as not to misinform.

Comment: @mickmackusa just happend as you commented!

Answer (score 0):

Just "mind games"

```
$arr = array_flip('email', 'serial', 'name','number'...);
if (count(array_filter(array_intersect_key($_SESSION, $arr))) == count($arr)) {
```

Comment: I do not recommend relying on `array_filter()`'s default/greedy behavior to filter the `$_SESSION` array.

Comment: What the problem Do you expect?

Comment: Monkey-wrenching value: `$_SESSION['number']='0';`

Comment: perhaps you could reduce function calls like this:  `if(array_intersect_key($arr,$_SESSION)==$arr){` ?

Comment: um, wait, my bad.  That is the default behavior of `empty()` too.  There is no unintended loss.

Comment: @mickmackusa  about comparing arrays - it's not the same due to different values in arr and session

Comment: You are right again, kind of.  I am comparing `$arr` to `$arr` (changed param order in `array_intersect_key()`). http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d73f5a0be17fcfb5bad5ae1b2862536084de82fd  My suggestion does not maintain the same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

This is just my opinion, but I think your expression is fine. Maybe you could format it in another way to make it more readable:

```
if ( !empty($_SESSION['email']) && 
     !empty($_SESSION['serial']) && 
     !empty($_SESSION['name']) && 
     !empty($_SESSION['number']) && 
     !empty($_SESSION['institution']) && 
     !empty($_SESSION['address']) &&
     !empty($_SESSION['item2']) ) {

     /* Proceed */

} else {

     /* Don't proceed */

}
```

Or maybe use a custom validation function:

```
/* My original version */
function filled_required_fields($fields, $array) {
    $valid = true;
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
        $valid = $valid && !empty($array[$field]);
        if (!$valid) return false;
    }
    return $valid;
}

/* Cleaner solution based on @caramba's answer */
function filled_required_fields($fields, $array) {
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
        if (empty($array[$field])) return false;
    }
    return true;
}


if (filled_required_fields(['email', 'serial', 'name', 'number', 'institution', 'address', 'item2'], $_SESSION) {

    /* Proceed */

} else {

    /* Don't proceed */
}
```

Comment: ...good a break point in the loop, but it could be written cleaner.

Comment: Thank you for your comments @mickmackusa! I'm sure it could be cleaner. I encourage you to write an answer so that we all could learn something! :)

Comment: I don't know, not mine.  Probably shouldn't copy someone else's method though.